# Как сделать столкновение двух анимированных блоков?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Пожалуйста помогите понять две вещи:

1.Как добавить столкновение двух анимированных `<div>` блоков?
2.К примеру у нас есть комната с хаотично-движущимися шарами(div-блоками).

Как сделать так, чтобы курсор был преградой для шаров и они ударялись об курсор (или касание,на смартфонах)?

Comment: Отслеживаете местоположение курсора, местоположение "шара", Если расстояние между ними становится <= диаметру шара, то по "формуле отскока" определяете новый вектор движания и пускаете тело дальше в путь ... с 2умя телами то же самое, только d*2 ... но вообще, такие штуки реализованы во многих игровых движках, покопайте в эту сторону.

Comment: Пытаюсь расковырять один браузер

Comment: А там на ...      так скажем бэкграунде  чтото типа комнаты с шарами и клик мыши раскидывает их по всему экрану

Comment: Взаимодействия объектов это непростая штука, все эти скорости, инерции и иже с ними. Если вы не понимаете что делать изначально, то самому писать такое смысла нет, ибо трата времени и сил, пробуйте найти библиотеку под подобные задачи, тот же http://phaser.io/, там и комьюнити неплохое и примеров хватает и проще чем самому все это продумывать (но это тоже далеко не самая простая штука).